# Remove all `null`s in an array without looping through in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following array:

```
const myArr = [null, null, null, null, 5, 6, null, null];
```

I know that the array at the end will contain:

- no `null`s and
- only unique values.

I want to stripe off all `null`s in the original array without using any loops (incl. `filter()`, `reduce()`). Is that possible? Maybe some kind of a `Set` that doesn't accept `null`s?

Comment: Why no loops? Even if you were to put them in a Set, there would likely need to be a loop behind the scenes to feed the array into the set.

Comment: Even if you use a set. To add all elements to the set (and remove the remaining `null` element afterwards) at least internally it will iterate over the array. How would it otherwise be able to add the elements, without looking at each of them

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was just curious....

Comment: You can send the data to a program written in another language... Or, if you know the index positions you can use splice. But that is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Simply make it a Set, then `delete(null)`

```js
const myArr = [null, null, null, null, 5, 6, null, null];
const s = new Set(myArr);
s.delete(null);
console.log(Array.from(s));
```

Comment: Yet, internally of course this will also loop over the array.

Comment: Nearly all array operations use a loop, right. @derpirscher

Comment: Of course they do. How would you add elements to a set without looking at each of them ...

Comment: I know, i just further explained my reasoning